# Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{n!}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n-y^n}{e^x-e^y}\,dxdy-2n\right)$

Tags: integration, limits, derivatives

Calculate$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{n!}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n-y^n}{e^x-e^y}\,dxdy-2n\right)$$

My solution:
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{x^n - y^n}{e^x - e^y} \, dx \, dy \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \, dx \int_0^x \frac{x^n - y^n}{1 - e^{-(x - y)}} \, dy \\
&= 2A_n + 2B_n,
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
A_n &= \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \, dx \int_0^x (x^n - y^n) \, dy \\
&= \int_0^\infty x^{n+1} e^{-x} \, dx - \frac{1}{n+1} \int_0^\infty x^{n+1} e^{-x} \, dx \\
&= (n+1)! - n! \\
&= n \cdot n!
\end{align*}

am I on right way?

Comment: https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM12011.pdf

Comment: How to find solutions like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could even go further if you followed the steps given [here](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Etauraso/AMM/AMM12011.pdf)
$$A_n=n \,n!$$
$$B_n=n!\left(1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac 1 {j\,(j+1)^{n+1} }   \right)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac 1 {j\,(j+1)^{n+1} }=(n+1)-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\zeta(k)$$

$$\frac{2A_n+2B_n}{n!}-2n=2 \sum _{k=2}^{n+1} \zeta (k)-2 n$$
But
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\zeta(n)-1)=1$$ and also

$$\sum _{i=2}^{n+1} \zeta (i)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac { \frac 1 {k^2}-\frac 1{k^{n+2}}} {1-\frac 1 k }$$